# How to only play microphone sound output in real-time?

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

Im using AudioRecord and AudioTrack to play the sound output from the microphone to the speakers.But **real-time playback creates sound echo**.I need to only play MIC sound and not the sound played by android system(which in this case is the MIC AudioTrack which is played for the second time).

```
            recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, 44100,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, N * 2);
        track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, N * 2,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

How to isolate microphone sound output in android and play it without playing whole the android sounds(other sounds which are played in android device,eg music played by a music player, notification sounds etc)

PS: found this comment after some researching on [this stackoverflow qs's comment by  hotpaw2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486291/how-to-amplify-audio-from-app-in-android) :

```
The latency on most Android devices between record and play is reported to be fairly  high, such that the user would hear a delayed echo unless isolated from any sound going  into the mic.
```

Comment: Is the issue simply the delay between the mike and the playback or is it a more serious issue where the user has the speaker on when they are using the app?

Comment: Speaker can not be used because the echo is devastating.The headphones are used for this purpose and echo is noticable which is unacceptable.

Comment: So, really your question is about minimizing total latency and has nothing to do with echo.

Comment: Latency can not be reduced to less than 200ms on android <4.1 devices. I was asking for a solution for just recording Mic input and not the sound playedback by device so the echo can be eliminated on headphones. Thanks for noticing and commenting anyways:-)

Comment: I am confused: the sound is coming out through your headphones, not the speakers, so how is it getting picked up by the device? If you have other sounds coming out of your speaker, you might be able to eliminate that with echo cancelation techniques, but the effect will be minimal. (I've seen other, related, q's on SO about this, btw).

Comment: Sound is comming from the MIC but when recording the sound from the MIC and you play a song using music player,then the music is recorded too(while headphones are on).I only need to record MIC input and not system sounds including played back sound.

Comment: why is there echo if sound is played through headphones?